# if have class show div else condition use JQuery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I tried to use JQuery to check one have my element have a class of x on hover will show other div, but my code is not working, not sure what I miss.

```
$(function(){
    if($('.naigation > li').hasClass('x')){
        $('.naigation > li').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#overlay').css('display','block');
        })
    }else if(!$('.naigation > li').hasClass('x')){
        $('#overlay').css('display','none');
        }
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('#overlay').css('display','none');
    })
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can see some errors on your code: for example, to what element the `mouseout` listener is register?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1)** We use of `mouseleave`, so no need `else if`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.naigation > li').mouseenter(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('x') )
      $('#overlay').css('display','block') ;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#overlay').css('display','none') ;
  });
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.naigation > li').mouseenter(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('x') )
      $('#overlay').css('display','block') ;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#overlay').css('display','none') ;
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}

#overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="naigation">
  <li class="x">Have X</li>
  <li>Have not X</li>
</ul>
<div id="overlay">Hello World!</div>
```

**Method 2)** Use of `.naigation > li.x` and remove `if` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.naigation > li.x').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#overlay').css('display','block') ;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#overlay').css('display','none') ;
  });
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.naigation > li.x').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#overlay').css('display','block') ;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#overlay').css('display','none') ;
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}

#overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="naigation">
  <li class="x">Have X</li>
  <li>Have not X</li>
</ul>
<div id="overlay">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.naigation > li.x').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#overlay').show();
        })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $('#overlay').hide();
    })
})
```

```css
#overlay{display:none}
.naigation{width:100%;float:left}
li{display:inline-block;width:100px;height:20px;background:#234;color:white;text-indent:1em;box-sizing:border-box;list-style:none;float:left;border:1px solid yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='naigation'><li class='x'>has X</li><li class='y'>not have X</li></div>
<div id='overlay'>overlay</div>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('.naigation > li.x').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#overlay').show();
        })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $('#overlay').hide();
    })
})
```